# How can I determine during which period of the day my record was made?

Tags: r, time, lubridate, period

In my dataset I have a parameter called visit_datetime. This parameter determines during which period the participant visited the researcher. This can be at any time a day. I want to give a value "1" if the visit was between 08.00 and 20.00, and value "2" if the visit was between 20.00 and 08.00. Is there an easy way to do this? For all other date/time calculations I use the package lubridate. The visit_datetime is parsed the right way, because other calculations do work.

I tried it like this:

`tijd_presentatie = ifelse(visit_datetime > hm("08:00") & visit_datetime < hm("20:00"), 1, 2)`

But this gives me always the value of "2".

Comment: In the past I had some problems with `ifelse` function. I suggest you to try with `if(condition){}else{}` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @R18 assuming `visit_datetime` is a vector with length > 1, `if` will throw an error. `ifelse()` is vectorized and is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using `lubridate::hour()`:

```
library(lubridate)

visit_datetime <- seq(ymd_hms("2023-02-14 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24)

tijd_presentatie <- ifelse(hour(visit_datetime) >= 8 & hour(visit_datetime) < 20, 1, 0)

data.frame(visit_datetime, tijd_presentatie)
```

```
        visit_datetime tijd_presentatie
1  2023-02-14 00:00:00                0
2  2023-02-14 01:00:00                0
3  2023-02-14 02:00:00                0
4  2023-02-14 03:00:00                0
5  2023-02-14 04:00:00                0
6  2023-02-14 05:00:00                0
7  2023-02-14 06:00:00                0
8  2023-02-14 07:00:00                0
9  2023-02-14 08:00:00                1
10 2023-02-14 09:00:00                1
11 2023-02-14 10:00:00                1
12 2023-02-14 11:00:00                1
13 2023-02-14 12:00:00                1
14 2023-02-14 13:00:00                1
15 2023-02-14 14:00:00                1
16 2023-02-14 15:00:00                1
17 2023-02-14 16:00:00                1
18 2023-02-14 17:00:00                1
19 2023-02-14 18:00:00                1
20 2023-02-14 19:00:00                1
21 2023-02-14 20:00:00                0
22 2023-02-14 21:00:00                0
23 2023-02-14 22:00:00                0
24 2023-02-14 23:00:00                0
```